# My name has/have five letters

Tags: verbs

What is correct:

> My name has five letters

or

> My name have five letters

I do not know which one is correct.

Comment: The correct answer is "my name has five letters".

Comment: I would say "There are five letters in my name."

Answer (score 2):

By identifying the object as a pronoun, we can figure if we need to apply the third person spelling rules:

- My name = it,
  hence *it **has** five letters* since *it* is used along with *he* or *she* to invoke the third person spelling rules.

Comment: I would add,  where and why you would use, **have** in other cases, and what the difference is between them.

Answer (score 0):

You would use **has** there because, **my name**. Is singular.
But if the subject in the sentence is plural then you would use **have**

> Our name(s) ***have*** five letters.

Comment: Although it would be more common to say `Our names each have five letters` or `Each of our names has five letters`.